# The solution to arithmetic brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, differential-equations

I would like to obtain an explicit solution to $X$ when it satisfies

$$dX_t = \mu X_t dt + \sigma dW_t, X_S = x$$

Here, $S > 0$, and we want an explicit solution for $X_T$, $T > S$.

I am not sure how to approach the problem. Seems more difficult than regular brownian motion!

Comment: I am voting this question as off-topic for being too basic. Hint 1: Compute the differential of $Y_t = X_t e^{-\mu t}$. Hint 2: This is a special case of an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process - search a bit and you'll find multiple related questions.

Answer (score 7):

To solve the SDE you should use the so called variation of constant method.
Define a process $Y_t=e^{-\mu t}X_t$, so that using Itô we obtain:
$$dY_t=-\mu Y_t dt+ e^{-\mu t}X_t=e^{-\mu t} \sigma dW_t $$
Therefore by integrating we have:
$$Y_T=Y_S+\int_S^T e^{-\mu t}  \sigma dW_t=e^{-\mu S} X_S +\sigma \int_S^T e^{-\mu t} dW_t$$
$$\Rightarrow \quad X_T=e^{\mu (T-S)} X_S +\sigma \int_S^T e^{\mu (T-t)} dW_t$$
This is a simple Ornstein Uhlenbeck process with mean reversion towards 0 if the coefficient $\mu$ is negative. I think you can easily find it in your Stochastic Calculus reference book.

Comment: The integration limits are wrong, no?

Comment: Yes you were right. I fixed it

Comment: @nsz, can you maybe explain how you got the dynamics of $Y_t$